# Random access on a huge file in haskell

Tags: haskell

What is the best way to read a huge file (around 1 TB) in haskell.
Basically the file contains a matrix of integer data. and I may need to (efficiently ) calculate the correlation between the different rows or between columns.

I have previously used pytables for this but was thinking of trying the same in haskell. I know haskell has some hdf5 bindings but is there any other options which I am not aware of ?

Comment: try Lazy `ByteString` from http://lambda.haskell.org/platform/doc/current/ghc-doc/libraries/bytestring-0.10.0.2/index.html

Comment: @viorior could you please elaborate, how lazy `bytestring` can be used for random access? E.g. how to read the last 1KB from 1TB file, and then 1KB from the middle, then 1KB from the beginning, etc? From what I see, it will crash with out-of-memory error.

Comment: @Yuras Same way as Roman suggest or using more specific library - `GHC.IO.Handle` and `GHC.IO.Handle.FD`

Comment: can we safely assume the platform to be 64bit?

Comment: @comonad , Yes in this particular case , my machine is a 64bit system. Just to give an overview , it is a windows 64-bit system. I am using haskell-platform. Though since the machine is not connected to the internet I end up having to download all packages and their dependencies manually and then installing them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could also give [*mmap*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/mmap) a try. For example, you can map a whole file as a `ByteString`:

```
import Data.ByteString as B
import System.IO.MMap

main = do
    bs <- mmapFileByteString "myLargeFile" Nothing
    let l = B.length bs
    print l
    -- print last 1024 bytes:
    let bs2 = B.drop (l - 1024) bs
    print (B.unpack bs2)
```

Cutting a piece out of it is fast - no data is copied. Then you can use whatever tool to parse `ByteString`s.

Comment: Fails when overcommit it turned off.

Answer (score 13):

As in any other language: you seek (using `System.IO.hSeek`), and then use binary IO (`Data.ByteString.hGet`). Then you parse the result (e.g. using attoparsec) and process as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Consider [iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/iteratee) package. It supports [seek](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/iteratee/0.8.9.4/doc/html/Data-Iteratee-Iteratee.html#v%3aseek), and [attoparsec-iteratee](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-iteratee) package provides integration with attoparsec.

The `hSeek` + `hGet` approach Roman suggested is low level. `iteratee` is higher level approach, but may be harder for beginners.